# How to run multiple Groovy/Grails version

Tags: grails, configuration, groovy

As I can run multiple versions of groovy / grails without having to change settings?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you manage developing with multiple versions of Grails using Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791560/how-do-you-manage-developing-with-multiple-versions-of-grails-using-windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on linux or osx, [theres a shell script here](https://github.com/deluan/grails.sh) which might help, and [an alternative script is here](http://naleid.com/blog/2009/03/08/bashzsh-aliases-to-switch-groovy-and-grails-version/)

Answer (score 7):

[GVM](http://gvmtool.net/) (Groovy enVironment Manager) is a great option if you're on Mac, Linux, Solaris, or  Windows with Cygwin.  GVM supports the installation and management of Groovy, Grails, Griffon, and Gradle.

If Grails is your primary concern and you use a Windows PC in a locked down enterprise where Cygwin isn't an option, look at [Gravy](http://www.enterprise-grails.com/2013/04/04/gravy/) or write a batch file as noted above.

Comment: Yes! This is the way to go!

Answer (score 3):

It's only about `GROOVY_HOME`/`GRAILS_HOME` and `PATH` environment variables. Start your Grails application from a `bat` file/shell script which sets these two variables, and you're fine.

Grails distinguishes settings stored in `home/.grails` for different versions, so versions won't clash there.

Answer (score 2):

I am using 7 grails version on my ubuntu machine . put the code below at the bottom of .bashrc file.

```
function switchGrails() {
```

echo “Switching to grails version: $1″

sudo rm /opt/grails

sudo ln -s /opt/$1 /opt/grails

echo “Done!”

}

alias grails225=’switchGrails “grails-2.2.5″‘

alias grails224=’switchGrails “grails-2.2.4″‘

alias grails223=’switchGrails “grails-2.2.3″‘

alias grails233=’switchGrails “grails-2.3.3″‘

alias grails235=’switchGrails “grails-2.3.5″‘

alias grails237=’switchGrails “grails-2.3.7″‘

alias grails2311=’switchGrails “grails-2.3.11″‘

After save and exit . Compile the .bashrc file . Type cd   and . .bashrc to compile .bashrc file.

For more reference : https://pkashyap28.wordpress.com/2014/09/11/manage-multiple-grails-application-in-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

Add a tip if you are working on Windows: there's a way for quick-changing version of GRAILS. You just need to change GRAILS_HOME & GROOVY_HOME (by script, GUI,...) then CLOSE the cmd window used to run grais-app, then start it again. By this way, the change will be applied and you can avoid restarting.

Answer (score 0):

Following the @tim_yates' answer. (unix based OS).

1- Put all grails versions under `opt` folder:

```
/opt/grails-2.3.1
/opt/grails-2.5.3
/opt/grails-3.1.1
```

2- Download and save [grails.sh](https://github.com/deluan/grails.sh) in somewhere you know. (I put mine at `/opt/grails-selector`)

Edit your `~/.bash_profile` file. The `PATH` var should point to the folder you put your grails.sh. And set `GRAILS_HOME` to your default version (in case you are creating a new project, for example, it'll use this default version unless you declare to use another.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/grails-selector
export GRAILS_HOME=/opt/grails-3.1.9
```

4- You're good to go. May you need to reopen your terminal or logout-login. When you call grails it will calls the grails.sh and then it looks for the version set in your project. So you it works automatically.